# How to get user payment info in android In-App purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I there a way to get a specific purchase amount and currency using In-app Billing Version 3 (I mean what the user actually paid, not the purchase plan details from google)?

From what I can see, all the info I can get is located at `Purchase` class:

```
String mItemType;  // ITEM_TYPE_INAPP or ITEM_TYPE_SUBS
String mOrderId;
String mPackageName;
String mSku;
long mPurchaseTime;
int mPurchaseState;
String mDeveloperPayload;
String mToken;
String mOriginalJson;
String mSignature;
```

and it doesn't contain price or currency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this outstanding issue: https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=93

The only price available is the one you get when querying the SKU details, and even then it will be formatted with the currency symbol and is only meant for direct user display. There is no price (formatted for display or otherwise) associated with a purchase.